# How to know the version of mdtool?

Tags: mono, osx-mavericks, monodevelop, mdtool

When using mdtool in terminal, I stumble upon what looks like [this bug fixed in 2012](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5318).

`mono --version` says 3.8.0, MonoDevelop is 3.0.5 and Xamarin Studio is 5.4 (all released long after 2012), but I also have old versions of Mono that I used to build from source.

How to know what version of `mdtool` I am running?
I tried `mdtool version`, `mdtool -version`, `mdtool --version`, none works.

Comment: `mdtool` is related to `MonoDevelop` see: [mdtool 3.0.5](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/monodevelop-3.0.5/main/src/tools/mdtool). But the bug (I think) was fixed in `MonoMac`.

Comment: I answer myself, I don't think your `MonoMac` has thoses bugs fixed. See: [MonoMac/Monodevelop 3.0.5](https://github.com/mono/monomac/tree/8575dd11ceff84c4e10eb9f5f1eb05d8046b269c)

Comment: @Gooseman: You linked to commit 8575dd1... does this commit has something in particular, or did you mean to link to https://github.com/mono/monomac in general?

Comment: It comes from here: [MonoDevelop external projects](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/monodevelop-3.0.5/main/external)